# Extracting a specific thing from a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, substring, stdstring

I have a string in the format `<a,b>`, which represents an edge in a directed graph (`a` is source and `b` is target). `a` and `b` are also strings themselves (for example, `a` can be `"Square"` and `b` is `"Circle"`).

I need to build a function which extracts `a`, and another function which extracts `b`.  So the signature will be:

```cpp
string getSource(String edge); //will return b
string getTarget(String edge); //will return a
```

I am using the `std::string` library to represent those strings.

I know that I need to find a way to find the `','` separating them in the middle of the string, and get rid of the `'<'` and `'>'`. But I couldn't find a function in `std::string` that will help me to do that.

How would you go about on doing this?

Comment: _"a is source and b is target"_ but `getSource()` returns b and `getTarget()` returns a!?

Comment: What about [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) and [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)? Should be all you need for simple cases.

Comment: The signature "String"  should be "string".  Also, "using namespace std;" is not a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good use case for a regex:

```
std::regex sd {R"(<(.*),(.*)>)"};
```

and then your functions can be written as:

```
std::string getSource(std::string const & edge) {
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex_match(edge, m, sd);
  return m[1].str();
}
```

and in `getTarget` you would return `m[2].str();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that the string is in the correct format, this is just a matter of using [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to locate the characters of interest and then constructing a new string from those iterators.  For example:

```
std::string getSource(std::string const & edge) {
    return {
        std::next(std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), '<')),
        std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), ',')
    };
}

std::string getTarget(std::string const & edge) {
    return {
        std::next(std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), ',')),
        std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), '>')
    };
}
```

If the strings are not in the correct format then these functions could exhibit undefined behavior.  This could be fixed trivially with the use of a helper function:

```
template <typename T>
std::string checkedRangeToString(T begin, T end) {
    if (begin >= end) {
        // Bad format... throw an exception or return an empty string?
        return "";
    }

    return {begin, end};
}

std::string getSource(std::string const & edge) {
    return checkedRangeToString(
        std::next(std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), '<')),
        std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), ',')
    );
}

std::string getTarget(std::string const & edge) {
    return checkedRangeToString(
        std::next(std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), ',')),
        std::find(std::begin(edge), std::end(edge), '>')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it belongs in a class whose constructor takes that `std::string` argument and parses it.

```
class edge {
public:
    edge(const std::string& str);
    std::string source() const { return src; }
    std::string target() const { return tgt; }
private:
    std::string src;
    std::string tgt;
};

edge::edge(const std::string& str) {
    auto comma = std::find(std::begin(str), std::end(str), ',');
    if (str.length() < 3 || comma == std::end(str) || str.front() != '<' || str.back() != '>')
        throw std::runtime_error("bad input");
    src = std::string(std::next(std::begin(str)), comma);
    tgt = std::string(std::next(comma), std::prev(std::end(str)));
}
```

I wouldn't use a regular expression for such a simple parse. Regular expressions are expensive and highly overrated.